# Upload Image with Active Record and Save Item with Reference to Session Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

2 questions really:
1) I am trying to save a note that belongs to the Client model (which also is used as login to create the session - therefore session[:id] = @client.id)
2)The note is an image, uploaded using ActiveRecord model.

Post request seems to be working fine but the note doesn't save. I am trying to only save the image first and client.id reference at first. The rest of the columns in the model will be filled in later using edit.

db schema contains the 2 ActiveRecord tables.
There seems to be no errors coming up but no new note is created (@note.save = false), which could be because currently nothing is being saved to a new note, just a new blob... in cmd you can see blob creation insert works fine, and then the next transaction is rolledback.
How would I add the logic to save @client.id in the note?

Below my code snippets...

**the form for from the view:**

```
<div class="image-upload">
        <h3>Upload image of sick note</h3>
        <div class="signup-form">
            <%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
                <%= f.file_field :image %>          
                <%= f.submit "Load Sick Note", class: "btn-submit" %> 
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The create in the controller:**

```
def create
        @note = Note.new(note_params)
        if @note.save 
            redirect_to '/' 
        else 
            redirect_to '/dashboard' 
        end 
    end

    private

    def note_params
        params.require(:note).permit(:image)
    end
```

**Note model:**

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
    has_one_attached :image
end
```

Comment: Is `@client` available in `create` action? If so you can just do `@note.client_id = @client.id`

Comment: Woops, there we go, I knew it could be something that simple. That fixes all issues. Cheers mate!

Comment: Check out my answer below. I show you a very "Rails" way to to this using the `.build()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`@note = Note.new(note_params)`

try

`@note = Client.new.notes.build(note_params)`

the `.notes` method (i.e. "`Client.new.notes`" ) comes from assuming you have a `has_many :notes` declaration in your `Client` model.

If you are only using a `has_one :note` declaration in your Client model then the `.build()` method will not work.

Comment: Awesome. If this helped please select it as the answer!